# Set delegate for QTreeWidget header

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qstyleditemdelegate

I need to set delegate for `QTreeWidget` header or make it working with HTML tags using other ways.

I set a delegate for `QTreeWidget` items using

```
ui->tree->setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

and it works.

But setting a delegate to the header does not work :

```
ui->tree->header()->setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work and it's documented here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#appearance

> Note: Each header renders the data for each section itself, and does not rely on a delegate. As a result, **calling a header's setItemDelegate() function will have no effect**.

Comment: This explains why it doesn't work, but it does not provide a solution.