# QComboBox in the header of a QTableview

Tags: qt, qtableview, qcombobox, qheaderview

I'd like to create a QCombobox in the header of a column of a QTableview. Any ideas to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set delegate for QTreeWidget header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478065/set-delegate-for-qtreewidget-header)

Comment: The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478065/set-delegate-for-qtreewidget-header) explains why `setItemDelegate` doesn't work, but it does _not_ give an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that has been valid for me is exposed here: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/04/11/qt-weekly-5-widgets-on-a-qheaderview/